# Progress bar of open/completed tickets over total tickets

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Front end of the progrss bar is looking good, but i am having problem with the back end. My problem is i can't get the correct amount of tickets especially total tickets. 
opened ticket in database should have value of 0

```
$row_count2 =  sqlsrv_query($NEI,"
                SELECT Count(Tickets.ID) AS Open_Tickets 
                FROM   (
                            (SELECT ID FROM TicketO  WHERE TicketO.Assigned = '0')                                      
                        ) AS Tickets
            ;",array($_GET['ID']));
    echo $r ? number_format(sqlsrv_fetch_array($row_count2)['Open_Tickets']) : 0;
           $open_tickets = number_format(sqlsrv_fetch_array($row_count2)['Open_Tickets']);
```

assigned tickets in database should have value of 1

```
    $row_count3 =  sqlsrv_query($NEI,"
                SELECT Count(Tickets.ID) AS Assigned_Tickets 
                FROM   (
                            (SELECT ID FROM TicketO  WHERE TicketO.Assigned = '1')                                      
                        ) AS Tickets
            ;",array($_GET['ID']));
    echo $r ? number_format(sqlsrv_fetch_array($row_count3)['Assigned_Tickets']) : 0;
            $assigned_tickets =  number_format(sqlsrv_fetch_array($row_count3)['Assigned_Tickets']);
```

but I cant get the total tickets, the code below is for total tickets of a location, but Im looking for total tickets of a person.

```
    $r = sqlsrv_query($NEI,"
                SELECT Count(Tickets.ID) AS Count_of_Tickets 
                FROM   (
                            (SELECT ID FROM TicketO WHERE TicketO.LID = ?)
                            UNION ALL 
                            (SELECT ID FROM TicketD WHERE TicketD.Loc = ?)
                            UNION ALL
                            (SELECT ID FROM TicketDArchive WHERE TicketDArchive.Loc = ?)
                        ) AS Tickets
            ;",array($_GET['ID'],$_GET['ID'],$_GET['ID']));
            echo $r ? number_format(sqlsrv_fetch_array($r)['Count_of_Tickets']) : 0;    
            $total = number_format(sqlsrv_fetch_array($r)['Count_of_Tickets']);
```

Comment: It's generally a good practice to omit the `;` in queries specified through a programmatic interface. They're not necessary, just add clutter.

Comment: Can you remove the php code? It's irrelevant to this question. Please leave the SQL code only. Also, why do you say it's wrong? Do you get an error, or the result number is wrong? What's the table structure?